# Only run GitHub Actions step if not a pull request

Tags: github-actions

I have a workflow which needs to execute either on a push or a pull request with the exception of the last step which pushes a package to NuGet (I don't want this to occur on a pull request, even to master).

How can I prevent the Publish NuGet step from running if the workflow is triggered from a pull request?

```yaml
name: .NET Core

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.101
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal
    - name: Publish NuGet
      uses: brandedoutcast/publish-nuget@v2.5.2
      with:
        PROJECT_FILE_PATH: "Orleans.Sagas/Orleans.Sagas.csproj"
        NUGET_KEY: ${{secrets.NUGET_KEY}}
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can inspect the [`github.event_name` context variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context) which contains the name of the event that triggered the workflow run.  (eg, `pull_request` or `push`)

In this case, you can run a step for all events whose name is not `pull_request` with a `github.event_name != 'pull_request'` conditional on your step.

For example:

```yaml
 - name: Publish NuGet
   uses: brandedoutcast/publish-nuget@v2.5.2
   with:
     PROJECT_FILE_PATH: "Orleans.Sagas/Orleans.Sagas.csproj"
     NUGET_KEY: ${{secrets.NUGET_KEY}}
   if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
```

Comment: Note that in most cases, you also want to combine this with a check for only the main branch, like this: `if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' && github.event_name != 'pull_request'`

Comment: When we add a new commit to a pull request, the `github.event_name` will be `push` instead of `pull_request`. The solution from @smoonin solves this

Comment: @James the main branch name is configurable, what if it is master for example?

Comment: Just a comment from January 2024. The `brandedoutcast/publish-nuget` action is no longer supported. Please use `dotnet pack` and `dotnet nuget push` instead.

Answer (score 9):

For future travellers, I found this action that worked quite well. I just needed to do an `if: needs.pr-check.outputs.number != 'null'` in order to filter by things being a PR or not.

https://github.com/8BitJonny/gh-get-current-pr

`github.event_name != 'pull_request'` did not work for me because the `on.pull_request` trigger doesn't exist for workflows that aren't launched by a PR.

Comment: It seems that now, it should be `if: needs.pr-check.outputs.number != null` without the quotes.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in 2023. The accepted answer does work perfectly though.